# Top repeated questions?

Tags: feature-request, questions, duplicate-questions

I know that in the Python tag, we have A LOT of repeated questions. One feature that might address this would be if the "top questions" list promoted duplicates above their numerical score.

One way of boosting them up would be to treat them as having their own score + the score of all questions marked as duplicates of that question.

Does this sound like a good idea?

Comment: As part of helping closing as appropriate dupes (and trying to group related questions and best answers etc...), there's http://sopython.com which is meant to be a collab. work on sorting out the Python related tags on SO... Although started many months ago - it's just one of those finding the time. Feel free to check it out though...

Comment: @JonClements Good to know.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's what the `Frequent` tab is all about - questions that have been asked, frequently.

For python:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/python?sort=frequent&pagesize=50

Comment: How does it work? How does it help here? How can the community use it? I've never noticed anything promoting its use, and if I don't know, there's no chance novice users do.

Comment: @Marcin - It lists questions in the order of number of duplicate links to it (how many other questions have been closed as its duplicate).

Comment: Well, I guess when I have an idea for how to promote use of this, I'll open a question about that.

Comment: I thought that what the OP was going for was identifying questions that are asked often, but either (a) not always explicitly identified as a duplicate or (b) may not all have been marked as duplicates of the *same* question.

Comment: @Oded number of duplicate links isn't quite the same as the summed score as the OP suggested, which would probably be a better measure of importance

Comment: @Joe to some extent, but sometimes people downvote questions just because they are duplicate (usually if it is something that is easy to search for).  That phenomenon could throw off the weighting by summed score idea.

Comment: @psubsee2003 to me that seems more like another indicator that the whole downvoting system is broken and doesn't add anything, but that's a topic for another question

Comment: @Joe - wondering why you think that. It is the #1 tool for keeping the content we want and getting rid of the content we don't.

Comment: @Oded Content that we do not want because it is Spam can be flagged and/or deleted. For content that is merely duplicate or not quite right for a particular SE site there are close (or move) votes. If content needs small fixes a comment is good to tell the poster what is wrong so they can fix it. Downvotes don't add any info *why* a post is bad and therefore don't really help anyone and IMO seem like a lazy option with great potential for abuse.

Comment: @Joe - Downvotes are a signal to other to look at a question for issues. For answers they tell people whether the community thinks an answer is good or not. It is important to let the community see these things at a glance. The other options are too hidden to be effective as a community moderation tool.

Comment: @Oded *Not upvoting* tells nearly the same story (especially after a few days). Especially on questions downvoting often just leads to confusion on the side of the asker.

Comment: @Joe - Not at all. Most people don't vote at all anyways. But not voting can easily just mean "I don't care enough" or "I don't have enough reputation" or "I am not register". Downvotes are meaningful.